# how to change the size(Width x Height) of applet by mouse click on the Button?

Tags: java, applet

I want to change the size(Width x Height) of applet by mouse click on the Button. I used resize(), but it does not get bigger than the area defined by html file. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript to resize the applet.  Use Java (in the applet) to call the JS.